# select radio button from database value

Tags: jsp, struts2, radio-button, ognl

I am trying to select radio button from database  value

I am trying

```
value="%{userInfoSettings[0].value}"
```

which is not selecting any radio box.

While iterating `userInfoSettings` it is showing the proper value.

```
   <s:iterator value="spList" var="r" status="st">
       <s:property value="description"/>
       <s:hidden name="uisList[%{#st.index}].settingParam.id" value="%{id}"/>
       <s:radio  name="uisList[%{#st.index}].value" 
                 list="#{'Yes':'Send email','No':'Dont inform'}"
                 value="%{userInfoSettings[0].value}"/>

         <s:iterator value="userInfoSettings" var="x">
              val <s:property value="value"/>
              id <s:property value="id"/>
         </s:iterator>
      id  <s:property value="id"/>
   </s:iterator>
```

How to solve this ?

Edit:

```
public class UserCommunication extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserInfoSetting> {

    UserInfoSetting uis = new UserInfoSetting();
    List<UserInfoSetting> uisList = new ArrayList<UserInfoSetting>();
    public String fetchAll() {
            setUisList(dao.fetchAll(lc.getSessionUserId()));
            for (UserInfoSetting a : getUisList()) {
                System.out.println(a.getId() + " " + a.getSettingParam().getId() + " " + a.getValue());
            }
            return SUCCESS;

    }
   //gettersetter
    @Override
    public UserInfoSetting getModel() {
        return uis;
    }

    }
```

UserInfoSetting.java

```
public class UserInfoSetting  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long id;
     private Atom atom;
     private SettingParam settingParam;
     private String value;
     private Timestamp adddate;
      //getter setter
      }
```

SettingParam.java

```
 public class SettingParam implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private int groupId;
    private Date adddate;
    private Set userInfoSettings = new HashSet(0);
    private Set userProfileSettings = new HashSet(0);
    private Set userPostSettings = new HashSet(0);
    private List<UserInfoSetting> userInfoSettingList = new ArrayList<UserInfoSetting>();
    private List<UserProfileSetting> userProfileSettingList = new ArrayList<UserProfileSetting>();
    private List<UserPostSetting> userPostSettingList = new ArrayList<UserPostSetting>();
    //gettersetter
}
```

Comment: Please show your java objects

Comment: What is the value of `userInfoSettings[0].value`?

Comment: its value is either 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: does userInfoSettings is set using c:set tag or similar?

Comment: No fetching data value from db on db it is yes or no

Comment: Try to printing `userInfoSettings[0]` and `userInfoSettings[0].value`. What do you get?

Comment: both of above not printing anything

Comment: That is the problem. Show your java objects as requested by Andrea in the first comment.

Comment: @xrcwrn: Your code is very confusing. You are iterating some unknown `spList` inside which you are accessing `userInfoSettings` and you are using modeldriven. The only `userInfoSettings` that is in your pojo is `Set` and if it is same as in jsp than you cannot get elements from `Set` by index, because `Set` doesn't have one. If you cannot do it in java class why do you think you can do it in jsp?

Comment: Ok. So how can we access `value` of `userInfoSettings` set

Comment: Inside SettingParam I have 3 lists to set values. I am fetching data in list to store in db using jdbc. and using set to fetch data using hibernate.

Comment: Seems like a bad design to me. How do you know that `userInfoSettings[0].value`, and not `userInfoSettings[1].value`, holds setting for sending email?

Comment: I tried this  `<s:iterator value="userInfoSettings" var="x" status="st">
                                                    ind <s:property value="%{#st.index}"/>
                                                    val <s:property value="value"/>
                                                    id <s:property value="id"/>
                                                </s:iterator>   Showing ind 0